# BotFramework WebChat not sending messages

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to run one of the botbuilders samples to check the opportunities of sending adaptive cards to several channels starting with webchat. The example can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/07.using-adaptive-cards

I managed to establish the connection with framework emulator, but when changing to test it in the azure console with the webChat test it seems that webChat is not able to send messages.

As I am using SDK V4 I understood that I do not have to care at all for the SSL Connection, neither I have to care about an A-category certificate - it's all done by the SDK/Framework.

So my bot is running as restify-server under the http protocol, but the configuration of the botservice indicates that the service endpoint should support https. Do I need to have worries about this?

Here the sample code:

````
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

const { AdaptiveCardsBot } = require('./bots/adaptiveCardsBot');

// Read botFilePath and botFileSecret from .env file.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create adapter. See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppID,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError] unhandled error: ${ error }`);

    // Send a trace activity, which will be displayed in Bot Framework Emulator
    await context.sendTraceActivity(
        'OnTurnError Trace',
        `${ error }`,
        'https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error',
        'TurnError'
    );

    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity('The bot encountered an error or bug.');
    await context.sendActivity('To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code.');
};

// Create the AdaptiveCardsBot.
const bot = new AdaptiveCardsBot();

// Create HTTP server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log('\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator');
    console.log('\nTo talk to your bot, open the emulator select "Open Bot"');
});

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        await bot.run(context);
    });
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

This likely doesn't have anything to do with HTTP(S)/SSL. It sounds like a deployment issue. Here is some [common deployment troubleshooting](https://github.com/meetshamir/SelfHelpContent/blob/master/articles/microsoft.bot/deploymentissues.md):

## Common Deployment Issues

### Recommended Steps

- Test to see if "Test in Web Chat" works from `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > Your Bot > Test in Web Chat`.

  - If it works, your deployment was successful and you need to troubleshoot why your client cannot connect to your deployed bot
  - If it doesn't work, please follow additional troubleshooting steps from this document
- If you ran into errors while executing deployment CLI commands, ensure you have the latest version of [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)

  - Some CLI commands will fail without much explanation. This is usually a formatting error. For your CLI commands, ensure that:
  - The entire command has appropriate spacing
  - User-provided strings are surrounded by quotes
  - User-provided strings for resource names are free of special characters (this mostly applies to App Service Plan names). See [Naming rules and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#naming-rules-and-restrictions) for specific details.
- Ensure that you ran [the `az bot prepare-deploy` step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#51-retrieve-or-create-necessary-iiskudu-files) prior to deployment. Missing this step often manifests in a bot not starting or 404 errors (due to missing/incorrect `web.config`) when visiting `https://<yourBot>.azurewebsites.net`
- Ensure that the file/folder structure of `https://<yourBot>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/` looks similar to your local bot. For Node bots, it will look mostly the same as your local bot files. For C# bots, it will have a lot of `Microsoft.*.dll` files along with `<yourBot>.dll`. All deployed bots should have a `web.config` file

  - For Node bots, you also need to have `node_modules` and `.env` deployed. For C# bots, you need `appsettings.json`. If your bot is missing `.env` or `appsettings.json` you need to either upload it, or copy the appropriate keys and values in `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > Your App Service > Configuration`
  - Expanding on [the code deployment step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#52-zip-up-the-code-directory-manually): When deploying, zip the **contents** of your project folder and **not** the folder by itself. Your zip file should have the structure:
  - `code.zip/[each project file and folder]` and **not** `code.zip/myBot/[each project file and folder]`
- Ensure that the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword that you have in `appsettings.json`/`.env`/`App Service Configuration` matches the ones found in your [App Registration](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade)
- Ensure that your App Registration can be accessed by "Accounts in any organizational directory" by following [these steps](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1366#issuecomment-479087524)
- Go to `https://<yourBot>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/:output`, click Run, and see if any errors present themselves in the Output window

### Recommended Documents

- [Deploy your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- For Virtual Assistants and Skills: [Manual Deployment](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/howto/virtual-assistant/manualdeployment/)
- [Set up continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

---

Please follow the document and let me know how it goes. If this turns out *not* to be a deployment issue, I will adjust this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, I found a temporary solution with ngrok, that proxies now in between my http server (bot) and the bot service.

Comment: But as my server address is exposed to the internet I still do not fully understand the connectivity concept. So for now I am fine, thanks. I will read the trouble shooting docs carefully when I come across that topic again.

Comment: @Andre. Sounds good. Let me know if there's anything you'd like me to inform you of. Feel free to "accept" my answer if it addressed your question/issue adequately.